# Is there a way to avoid duplicated code while creating a function in rvalue and lvalue references?

Tags: c++, templates

Sometimes when i'm creating a function it needs a rvalue reference version, as example:

```
template<typename T> void printCont(T &Cont){
    for (auto &i : Cont)
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

So i can print any container like `std::vector` but i would need to manage some rvalues to be printed directly

```
template<typename T> void printCont(T &&Cont){
    for (auto &i : Cont)
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

So i can call it as `printCont(myclass.getVector())` as example.
(in this example would be to easy to just copy the content to print in this version, to a lvalue vector, but in real world programs, do this would make our program slower)

But as you can see, BOTH FUNCTIONS HAVE THE SAME CODE. Is i know, duplicated code is a mistake in good practices. So my question is about... is there a way to call the lvalue version of the function from the rvalue version or viseversa? Is there a way to avoid this duplicated code? Imagine i create two 2000lines function and i need to create both version of it, it would be a waste of lines just do "Control+C" and "Control+V".

Comment: `printCont(myclass.getVector())` : that will also work with the first version of the function without incurring an extra copy, btw.

Comment: @Frank not if `myclass.getVector()` returns an rvalue

Comment: @M.M ahhhh, that's right. (assuming you mean a rvalue reference)

Comment: @Frank I mean an rvalue  (which can be xvalue or prvalue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second function:

```
template<typename T> void printCont(T &&Cont)
```

it is actually a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), which means it can be called with both lvalue and rvalue arguments. If called with an lvalue then `T` deduces to lvalue reference type. You can remove the first version from your code.

---

Another option, since your code does not modify the operand, is to use:

```
template<typename T> void printCont(T const& Cont)
```

which also will accept both lvalues and rvalues.

---

> (in this example would be to easy to just copy the content to print in this version, to a lvalue vector, but in real world programs, do this would make our program slower)

This makes no sense, it seems you have some misunderstanding about lvalues and rvalues.